# docker run failed at "python3: can't open file"

Tags: python-3.x, linux, docker, dockerfile

My code is in directory /test-scripts, details structure is as follows.

```
/test-scripts
│___Dockerfile 
│
└───requirements.txt
....
|
└───IssueAnalyzer.py
```

Run the following command in directory /test-scripts.

/test-scripts(master)>

```
docker run --rm -p 5000:5000 --name testdockerscript testdockerscript:1.0
python3: can't open file '/testdocker/IssueAnalyzer.py -u $user -p $pwd': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

And my Dockerfile content is as follows.

```
FROM python:3.6-buster

ENV PROJECT_DIR=/testdocker

WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR

COPY requirements.txt $PROJECT_DIR/.

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -yy install libmariadb-dev

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . $PROJECT_DIR/.

CMD ["python3", "/testdocker/IssueAnalyzer.py -u $user -p $pwd"]
```

Use $user, $pwd above to replace the real value in this question.
In my opinion, the file IssueAnalyzer.py will be copy from current directory /test-scripts to /testdocker, but actually it is not. Please help to let me know how to change this Dockerfile. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 different way to define the CMD: exec form and shell form.

You're using the exec form but you're not splitting the command correctly.

For this specific case, I suggest to use the shell form:

```
[...]

CMD python3 /testdocker/IssueAnalyzer.py -u $user -p $pwd
```

If you really want to use the exec form:

```
[...]

CMD ["python3", "/testdocker/IssueAnalyzer.py", "-u $user", "-p $pwd"]
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: Note that these produce very different results.  The first form produces separate arguments `-u` and the value of the `$user` environment variable; the second form produces a single argument exactly `-u $user` with a space and a dollar sign, and no environment variable expansion.

Comment: @Stefano Thank you! It works now. But when i build this docker image in another server, it show errors "INFO[0014] Cannot mkdir: /c4_working/testdocker is not a directory". But exactlly this directory was already created before docker build.

Comment: details error info:
...

Step 1 : ENV PROJECT_DIR /c4_working/testdocker
 ---> Running in 1d8ff08aa44d
 ---> b721272ea61b
Removing intermediate container 1d8ff08aa44d
Step 2 : WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR
 ---> Running in 87e901d8928a
 ---> 391ceb2614e6
Removing intermediate container 87e901d8928a
Step 3 : COPY requirements.txt $PROJECT_DIR/.
 ---> 7fbd830c1368
Removing intermediate container b9a3f10a5045
Step 4 : RUN apt-get update     && apt-get -yy install libmariadb-dev
 ---> Running in cadc9925b22f
INFO[0014] Cannot mkdir: /c4_working/testdocker is not a directory